# "Property 'extend' does not exist on type Vue" error, when running unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-component

I have created a Vue component and a unit test to validate its behavior. I can use the component on my Vue app without any issues, but when I run my unit test using jest, I get the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'extend' does not exist on type 'typ
eof import("</path/to/module>")'.

    1 export default Vue.extend({
```

**vButton.ts - Component under test**

```
export default Vue.extend({
  template: `
  <div>
    <button class="default-button" @click="click">
      <span>{{ text }}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  `,
  props: {
    text: String,
    action: Function
  },

  methods: {
    click(): void {
      this.$emit('action');
    }
  }
});
```

**vButton.spec.ts - unit test**

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import vButton from '../views/core/ts/components/vButton'

describe('vButton', () => {
  describe(':props', () => {
    it(':text - should render a button with the passed-in label text', () => {
      const msg = 'new message';

      const wrapper = mount(vButton, {
        propsData: { text: msg },
      });

      expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg);
    });
  });

  describe('@events', () => {
    it('@click - should emit an "action" event when the button is clicked', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(vButton);
      const button = wrapper.find('button')

      button.trigger('click')

      expect(wrapper.emitted().action).toBeTruthy()
    })
  });
});
```

I expect Vue.extend to work fine when running the unit test.